# Verification proof, if $\det(A^5) = 0$ then $A$ is singular

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, solution-verification

Say we have a square matrix whose $\det(A^5) = 0$, then $A$ must be singular.

**My proof:**

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix, and let the $\det(A) = m$.

$\det(A^k) = (\det(A))^k = m^k$

$m^k = 0 \iff m = 0$

If $m = 0$, $A$ is singular (properties of determinants)

Q.E.D.

I realize this proof is probably too informal, but I'm not sure how else to put it.

Would you guys see this as satisfying enough, or am I lacking something crucial? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Another way to put it (not sure how the formal way would be though), is to say $det(A^k) = det(A)det(A)$ $k$ times..

Comment: It’s a fine proof. If you haven’t proven $\det(A^n)=(\det(A))^n$ you can prove it by induction using $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B).$

Comment: Looks fine to me

Comment: Thank you! I think I did miss the fact that I didn't prove $det(A^k) = (det(A))^k$ though...

Comment: If $A$ is non-singular then $A^5$ is non-singular, and therefore $\det(A^5)\neq 0$. So you don't really need that property.

Comment: Well, I think I already provided a on liner: "If $A$ is non-singular then $A^5$ is non-singular, and therefore $\det(A^5)\neq 0$".

Comment: @Yorch yes but you would need to prove that if $A$ is non singular, then $A^5$ is non singular, right?

Comment: Yes that  true. but the proof of that is rather straightforward :) and is just: $(A^5)((A^{-1})^5) = (A^{-1})^5A^5 = I$

Comment: It does, but it doesn't need the multiplicative property of the determinant. It only uses the property that $\det(A) = 0 \iff A \text{ is singular }$

Comment: But here again, you're saying $(A^5)((A^{-1})^5) = (A^{-1})^5A^5 = I$ which is only true if $A$ is invertible

Comment: I am trying to prove the claim : if $A$ is singular then so is $A^5$, so I can assume $A$ is singular.

Comment: In any case, your proof is fine. I just wanted to say that the multiplicative property of the determinant is not required.

Comment: I think I'm a bit confused about your proof :P @Yorch but I've improved my proof so it seems fine. Using simple induction like Thomas said, $\det(AB) = \det(A) \det(B)$ repeatedly

Comment: Whatever makes you happy makes me happy.

Comment: :P Thanks for your help @Yorch